# Record and store multiple audio files

Tags: android

I have set up an activity called *Say Sentence* which records audio from the user when a "Start Speaking" button is pressed, and then stops recording when the "Stop Speaking" button is pressed. It then saves the file in a sub-directory named *SaySentence* which is in the main application's folder. I managed to get my code working so that it saves one audio file called *saysentence.3gpp* and replaces it every time the user records again.

However, I would like to have it set up so that the user can record multiple files, maybe naming them something like saysentence001.3gpp, saysentence002.3gpp, etc.

Here is my current Activity:

```
public class SaySentence extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private String OUTPUT_FILE;
    private TextView mStatus;
    private TextView mRecorded;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_say_sentence);

        String sep = File.separator;
        String newFolder = "SaySentence";
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + sep + "AudioRecordingTest" + sep + newFolder);
        myNewFolder.mkdir();

        OUTPUT_FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ sep + "AudioRecordingTest" + sep + newFolder + sep + "saysentence.3gpp";
        mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        mRecorded = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRecorded);

    }

    public void startSpeaking(View view) {
        try {
            beginRecording();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopSpeaking(View view) {
        try {
            stopRecording();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void beginRecording() {
        ditchMediaRecorder();
        File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);

        mStatus.setText("Recording");

        if(outFile.exists()){
            outFile.delete();
        }

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        recorder.start();

    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mStatus.setText("Recording Stopped");
        mRecorded.setText("Audio file saved to: " + OUTPUT_FILE);

        if(recorder != null){
            recorder.stop();
        }

    }

    private void ditchMediaRecorder() {
        if(recorder != null) {
            recorder.release();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I easily implement the feature to allow my application to record and store multiple audio files?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to choose from

1. Check first the files in your folder. Count the number of files and the count result +1 will be your new file name.
2. Use SharedPreferences. Track the number of files in your shared preferences.

Comment: How do I utilize SharedPreferences?